# Is there a 64-bit app for working with image sequences to replace Quicktime 7?

Tags: video, quicktime, catalina, 64-bit

I've been using Quicktime 7's "Movie to Image Sequence" and "Open Image Sequence" export and import options forever. It's useful for creating and working with time-lapses, modifying a single frame or a couple of frames in a video, creating short animated gifs, etc.

Unfortunately Quicktime 7 is 32-bit, so once I upgrade to Catalina it will be gone forever. I'd like a recommendation for a 64-bit app with similar features: the ability to export every frame of a movie to a sequence of still images, and construct a new movie at a specified frame rate from a set of still images.

Is there any good replacement for this Quicktime 7 feature? Free is optimal but not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

## ffmpeg

The command line tool [`ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org) can be used to create videos from images:

- [How to create a video from images with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg)
- [How to create a video from images using FFmpeg?](https://superuser.com/questions/624567/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: I could live with that. The only requirement I had was if FFmpeg can go the other way and extract every frame from a video.

Answer (score 1):

***QuickTime Player*** in Cataline (and probably earlier versions) allows you to import an image sequence exactly as with QuickTime 7 and export it as a movie.

Open QuickTime Player. Go to `File > Open Image Sequence` and select the images or folder that you want to use in your timelapse. Now you get an option to select resolution, frame rate, and encoding.

**Note!** I have had some issues getting it to import all selected images. What instead works for me is to select the folder with the images for my timelapse, then it correctly imports all of the images.

Unfortunately, I have not seen an option for doing the opposite in QuickTime Player in Cataline, i.e. importing a video and exporting it as an image sequence.

[image]

[image]